# In "My Neighbor Totoro", what is wrong with the mother (why is she in the hospital)?

Tags: my-neighbor-totoro

Title says it all:  In "My Neighbor Totoro", what is wrong with the mother (i.e. why is she in the hospital)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this site](http://www.nausicaa.net/miyazaki/totoro/faq.html), in particular [this internal link](http://www.nausicaa.net/miyazaki/totoro/faq.html#mother):

> It was implied that her illness was tuberculosis. In the novelized
>   version of "Totoro" (illustrated by Miyazaki), it was stated that Mom
>   was suffering from TB. Shichikokuyama Hospital, where she was staying,
>   had a good reputation for treating TB, and that's why they moved
>   there. The house they moved into was originally built a long time ago
>   by a rich city man whose wife was suffering from TB. Granny used to
>   work as a domestic for this lady, but the lady died. That's why the
>   house is somewhat different from the other village houses, more
>   Westernized, with gables.
>
> This is a bit autobiographical: Miyazaki's mother suffered for many
>   years from spinal TB, and she was away from home for a long time.

But from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Neighbor_Totoro) (spoiler):

> The girls perch in a tree outside of the hospital, overhearing a
>  conversation between their parents and discovering that she has been
>  kept in hospital by a minor cold and is otherwise doing well.

Comment: The spoiler content doesn't say what she actually had, only that she had a cold in addition to whatever she was already suffering from.

Comment: @Catija True, but it kinda spoils the end, doesn't it?